# How to completely remove kvantum manager?

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, kde

I recently uninstalled `kde-plasma` and transferred to GNOME, now I want to remove `kvantum` manager completely. I am not able to remove with this code `sudo apt remove kvantummanager` or `sudo apt remove kvantum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy bro, just use this code to remove kvantum manager: `sudo apt remove qt5-style-kvantum qt5-style-kvantum-themes`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suggest you also mention *how* to find out which packages are the relevant ones.